# Copy a file from local to remote root-only folder (/usr/local/bin) using Paramiko?

Tags: linux, ansible, file-permissions, paramiko

I need to copy a file from local to remote `/usr/local/bin`. I am already using `paramiko` for some other copy actions.

I saw some solutions online on how to avoid the permission error:

- https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=sudo+paramiko.put
- [How to run sudo with Paramiko? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270677/how-to-run-sudo-with-paramiko-python)
- [Paramiko Python: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144286/paramiko-python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

All these solutions:

> - changing who owns the directory
> - adding a user to the group of the directory
> - creating a new group and changing the group on the directory
> - changing the owner
> - Changing the r/w permissions of owner,group, or public.

Don't feel right when working with `/user/local/bin`.

I also have the option to just copy the file to `~/file` to later on move it using an `ansible` script (which is executed on the remote anyway), but splitting the copying process feels wrong, too.

Directly logging into `sudo` would be possible since I can enable remote root login, but that sounds like a security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login with the root to have access to folders that require the root access.

For a general discussion on this topic (and why direct root login is not such security problem as commonly believed), see
[Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663)

---

If your server does not allow direct root login (and you did try to make it happen), you have to find some workaround. Paramiko won't (cannot) help you anyhow with bypassing server's security mechanisms.

Some options:

- Upload the files to a folder you have a wrote access too, and then automate shell commands (via `sudo`/`su`) to copy the files to the final root-only destination.
- Run Paramiko SFTP via `sudo`/`su`. You would have to implement an alternative to [`SFTPClient.from_transport`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.from_transport) that will call something like `chan.exec_command('sudo su -c /bin/sftp-server')` instead of `chan.invoke_subsystem("sftp")`.

Comment: Your answer solves the question given above. However, for my project I decided to first copy the files to the home directory and then later to `/usr/local/bin` using Ansible. This feels more natural to me than changing paramiko's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- name: Copy my file to root owned directory
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: /path/to/local-file
    dest: /usr/local/bin
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0750
  become: true
```

Or if the file is already on your remote

```yaml
- name: Copy my file to root owned directory
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    remote_src: true
    src: /path/to/remote-file
    dest: /usr/local/bin
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0750
  become: true
```

Note: the user used to connect to your remote target must have full sudo rights. See [Ansible privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)

Comment: I edited my question and clarified that `ansible` is only running remotely not locally. So copying using `ansible` locally while possible feels a bit odd. But I will definitely consider it.